# cocos2d-x ver3 action blink in Sequence doesn't executes , single action does

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i have strange situation where i try to run blink action as part of Sequence 
on sprites Although the method getNumberOfRunningActions returns 1 the sprite dosn't blink.

where pMatchedSymbolArray is array of ReelSymbol Sprite extendet class

```
class ReelSymbol :public Sprite 
{
    public:

        CREATE_FUNC(ReelSymbol);
        ReelSymbol();
        virtual bool init();         
        void setup();
        static ReelSymbol* createWithSpriteFrameName(const std::string& spriteFrameName);


    private:
        int getIntFromName(std::string key);
        Settings* pSettings;




};


for(ssize_t a=0; a<pMatchedSymbolArray->count();a++)
{

       auto actionBlink = Blink::create(2, 5);
       auto repeat = Repeat::create(actionBlink, 2); 
       ReelSymbol* symbol = ((ReelSymbol*)pMatchedSymbolArray->getObjectAtIndex(a));
       auto actionSequence = Sequence::create(
                                                actionBlink,
                                                DelayTime::create(2),
                                                CallFunc::create( std::bind(&LinesManager::AnimationUnitCallback, this, symbol,pMatchedSymbolArray->count()) ),
                                                NULL); 
        ReelSymbol* thisReelSymbol = ((ReelSymbol*)pMatchedSymbolArray->getObjectAtIndex(a));
        thisReelSymbol->runAction(actionSequence);
        int no = thisReelSymbol->getNumberOfRunningActions();
        CCLOG("getNumberOfRunningActions: %d",no);
} 


void LinesManager::AnimationUnitCallback(Node* sender,int iMatchedSymbolArrayCount)
{



}
```

the sprite blink only if i run:

```
auto actionBlink = Blink::create(2, 5); 
....
....
thisReelSymbol->runAction(actionBlink );
```

what can be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is problem with only recent version then workaround might be using two actions simultaneously.

1. Blink action with duration.
2. Sequence with Delay of Blink action and followed by other actions.

Comment: no idea about fix. But you can report in cocos2dx forums?

Comment: man the answering really socks in the forum they hardly answer you 
its great software but almost 0 support on forum and they break/change
allot on each version with out dated documents ...

Comment: It's maintained by people around the world and its free and open community.  I know there is frequent API changes and lack of documents but it saves your huge amount of development time. So I suggest you to keep working with latest version and keep supporting in forum too.

Comment: allots of ppl working on it even getting pay check , but hell 
they can't ship something without break something else and the documentation is broken ... hu what ever

Comment: It has been around 2 years I have been working on game development with Cocos2dx and it's earlier versions API were not designed with best practices but I believe latest iteration is quite useful for cross platform. Though now some community peoples have started writing books and docs.

Comment: yeah i know all this , im working one year with the frame work and i changed API and way things work 4 times already .
and now i downloaded the latest version and again changed ...

Comment: 'cocos2d::Object': was declared deprecated
cocos2d::Node::draw': function declared as 'final' cannot be overridden by 'HelloWorld::draw' 
man im using Object all over and what is with the draw now ...

Comment: `Object` is replaced by `Ref`. Just do a find and replace all on it. The `draw()` just the method signature has changed. A find and replace all on this works too.